Key fob only works when battery is exposed
I have a 2016 Honda fit. My key fob got replaced a couple years ago and the fob I got is kinda jank and only turns on my car if it’s close to the button, but that’s my only issue with it. Today my key battery light lit up on my dash. I left my car unlocked (thankfully) and went inside to change the battery. Since I haven’t had to swap this battery since the replacement, it was SUPER hard to pop open and SUPER hard to close. I got in my car, tried to turn it on and I got the “no key” beep. I was playing around with the fob, decided to pop it back open, tried to turn on the car again and it turned on. I thought “cool it’s fixed”, closed the fob, shut the driver door and got the beep again. So now my fob only works if it’s open and exposing the battery. There’s no way I can leave it like this. I don’t want to lose it or mess up the inside.
side note I have no turn key. I bought the car used and it didn’t come with one so I gotta figure this out

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
